# How to change and animate NSLayoutConstraints programmatically?

Tags: ios, core-animation, nslayoutconstraint

I'm defining a complex layout via NSLayout constraints, programmatically. Now I found myself in a situation in which I need to animate one of the elements.

I need to animate view crossFadeControlView changing it's height. This will obviously imply that the other will need to dynamically shrink. Is that possible?

If not... what are my options?

Below are my constraints:

```
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[clipGrid]    [sceneLaunchView(==117)][meter(==9)][tempoControl(==58)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[tracksView][meter(==9)][tempoControl(==58)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[crossFadeControlView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[clipGrid]-3-[tracksView(==143)][crossFadeControlView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[sceneLaunchView]-3-[tracksView][crossFadeControlView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tempoControl][crossFadeControlView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[meter][crossFadeControlView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. It's a little hard to tell what's where from your constraints, but for instance, if you change the height of crossFadeView, clipGrid will automatically shrink since it has no explicit height set, while tracks view will maintain its height since it does have a defined height. screenLaunchView, tempoControl, and meter will also shrink automatically for the same reason.

To change the height of crossFadeView, you'll have to create a height constraint for it, and then change the constant value of that constraint. I usually do that right above my animation block then call layoutSubviews on the superview in the animation block.

Comment: Thx for the reply. How can I create such constraint? Should I get it from the already defined constraints? Or should I create a new constraint? If so, I how is that made? I still didn't find anything that lead me in that direction. Thx

Comment: Hi again. I was able to create the following constraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:crossFadeControlView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:tracksView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.5 constant:0]; I just can't get it to have a 0 height. But it is animating already! :)

Comment: @NunoSantos, well, you're never going to get it 0 if you're saying it's half of tracksView which has a height of 143. If you don't need it related to anything else, the easiest way is to make an outlet to a  height constraint you make in IB, then just change the constant value in code.